# How do I use mutator and accessor function for my array to display the output?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm having trouble understanding and how to display my input from my external file mycountrydata.txt by using my class functions to assign my variables in my array to my output. Did I do something wrong with my classes or am I placing or using my Set and Get the wrong way? Also please tell me why must it by like that?

This is my external file mycountrydata.txt:

> China
>
> 1,357,380,000
>
> 9,596,961
>
> France
>
> 66,616,416
>
> 640,679
>
> United States
>
> 320,206,000
>
> 9,857,306
>
> South Korea
>
> 51,302,044
>
> 100,210
>
> Japan
>
> 126,434,964
>
> 377,944

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Country{

    private:
        string name;
        long population;
        double area;
        
    public:
        Country();
        Country(string, long, double);
        void setName(string);
        void setPopulation(long);
        void setArea(double);
        string getName();
        long getPopulation();
        double getArea();
        
  };

Country::Country(){
  name="?";
  population=0;
  area=0;
 }

Country::Country(string name1, long population1, double area1){
  name=name1;
  population=population1;
  area=area1;
}

void Country::setName(string name1){
 name=name1;
}

void Country::setPopulation(long population1){
  if(population1>=0.0)
    population=population1;
  else{
    population1=0.0;
    cout<< "Invalid number. Setting population to 0."<<endl;
 }
}

void Country::setArea(double area1){
if(area1>=0.0)
    area=area1;
 else{
    area1=0.0;
    cout<< "Invalid number. Setting area to 0."<<endl;
  }
}

string Country::getName(){
 return name;
}

long Country::getPopulation(){
 return population;
 }

double Country::getArea(){
 return area;
 }

int main(){


const int H=5;
string homename[H];
long homepopulation[H];
double homearea[H];
Country home(homename[H], homepopulation[H], homearea[H]);
ifstream infile("mycountrydata.txt");

    home.setName(homename[H]);
    home.setPopulation(homepopulation[H]);
    home.setArea(homearea[H]);

for(int i=0; i<H; i++){
    
    infile>>homename[i];
    infile>>homepopulation[i];
    infile>>homearea[i];

    cout<<"Country: "<<home.getName()<<endl;
    cout<<"Population: "<<home.getPopulation()<<endl;
    cout<<"Area: "<<home.getArea()<<endl<<endl; 

}
infile.close();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: You declare several arrays with five (`H`) indices (0 through 4, inclusive). You then go on to access past the end by using `H` to specify which one to access. This will cause undefined behavior. Beyond that, it's unclear to me what you're asking.

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is how could I use my classes to assign my values from the external file to display in the output.

Answer (score 0):

May be like here:

```
Country home;
ifstream infile("mycountrydata.txt");
for(int i=0; i<H; i++){
    infile>>homename[i];
    infile>>homepopulation[i];
    infile>>homearea[i];

    home.setName(homename[i]);
    home.setPopulation(homepopulation[i]);
    home.setArea(homearea[i]);

    cout<<"Country: "<<home.getName()<<endl;
    cout<<"Population: "<<home.getPopulation()<<endl;
    cout<<"Area: "<<home.getArea()<<endl<<endl; 
}
```

Comment: And actually you don't need H homenames/homepopulations/homeareas. You can rewrite one value on each iterations.

Comment: Well this shows the output, but im getting this:                                                                                           Country: China
Population: 1
Area: 0

Country:
Population: 4233695
Area: 2.70194e-307

Country:
Population: 4285072
Area: 1.32725e-317

Country:
Population: 240196
Area: 1.2732e-313

Invalid number. Setting population to 0.
Country:
Population: 240196
Area: 1.94589e-307


--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.009906 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: remove commas from external file

Comment: Now the output is:                                                                                                          Country: China
Population: 1357380000
Area: 9.59696e+006

Country: France
Population: 66616416
Area: 640679

Country: United
Population: 0
Area: 1.32725e-317

Country:
Population: 240196
Area: 1.2732e-313

Invalid number. Setting population to 0.
Country:
Population: 240196
Area: 1.94589e-307


--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.01407 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Also how does comma affect the external file? I'm new to c++ and curious why does it do that.

Comment: and replace ' ' (space) in country name on '_'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help,  Konstantin.Krivyakin.